# 2-approximation for TSP-metric

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I got stuck with the following question:

Consider the following heuristic: Start with a tour containing only one vertex. At each step, find the vertex outside the tour with the lesser distance to some vertex of the tour. Let v be the outter vertex and u be the inner vertex. Add v right after u in the tour. After adding all vertex, connect the last and the first one through their edge. Suppose that your edges follow the triangle distance property. How can we show that this heuristic is a 2-approximation for the TSP-metric problem?

Does anyone know how to start that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, this prescription makes a tree...  (It can never make a cycle since doing so would require joining two vertices both already in the path.)

Comment: Hi @EricTowers, indeed there was a missing step. I've editted it, does it make more sense now?

Comment: What approximation ratio do you get by traversing the tree in depth-first order, skipping vertices you've already visited.  This might be called "walking around the tree".

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not following. Which tree exactly are you mentioning? The one constructed before the last step?

Comment: Yes.  The last edge is not necessary to get the 2-approximation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean_TSP

Comment: Are you pointing out that the tree this algorithm generates is a minimum-spanning tree of the graph?

Comment: Note that this algorithm looks like Prim's, but they're slightly different - when you find a light edge crossing a cut in Prim's algorithm, it gets permanently in the solution. In this algorithm, when you add a vertex between two others, you change the previous edge configuration. For instance, if you have the set of vertex {u, v} and add a vertex w between them, Prim would produce the edges {u-v and u-w}. This heuristic, however, produces {u-w-v} and discards {u-v}

Comment: Ah.  Then I withdraw my comment.